# xarray DataArray failed to convert to netcdf file

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I want to convert DataArray object:

```
print(dO18Buton)
```

> <xarray.DataArray 'dO18' (time: 480, latitude: 3, longitude: 4)>
> array([[[-4.880011 , -5.124271 , -5.3803325, -5.6058764],
> [-5.3377748, -5.833566 , -5.9842467, -5.876422 ],
> [-6.014824 , -5.9881806, -5.3263307, -5.022347 ]],
>
> ```
>    [[-5.160749 , -6.0551167, -6.506145 , -6.2277913],
>     [-6.419599 , -6.5028667, -6.3349605, -6.0087442],
>     [-6.793201 , -7.4350834, -8.72767  , -9.683132 ]],
>
>    [[-3.7316084, -4.0689707, -4.8186183, -5.7664514],
>     [-4.2518973, -4.527271 , -5.304754 , -6.1962605],
>     [-5.832672 , -5.5838227, -5.449891 , -5.5966973]],
>
>    ...,
>
>    [[-2.5347471, -2.7267933, -2.4660826, -2.6986003],
>     [-2.5378466, -2.4775863, -2.3831725, -2.4046302],
>     [-2.6648045, -2.6119947, -2.4898052, -2.6828647]],
>
>    [[-3.6972165, -3.9601326, -4.220426 , -4.639566 ],
>     [-4.910946 , -5.022526 , -5.248487 , -5.4792166],
>     [-6.3120723, -6.1730146, -5.925238 , -5.7671666]],
>
>    [[-6.1374903, -4.9562454, -4.483402 , -4.5176744],
>     [-7.894933 , -7.206261 , -6.434858 , -6.016612 ],
>     [-7.5923204, -7.699311 , -7.642746 , -7.5549483]]], dtype=float32) Coordinates:   * time       (time) datetime64[ns]
> ```
>
> 1979-01-01 1979-02-01 ... 2018-12-01   * longitude  (longitude)
> float64 120.0 121.9 123.8 125.6   * latitude   (latitude) float64
> -6.667 -4.762 -2.857 Attributes:
> description:  dO18precip
> units:        per mil

into a netcdf file using `to_netcdf()` method, but got this error related to the `datetime` conversion:

```
dO18Buton.to_netcdf('dO18Buton.nc',
               engine='netcdf4')
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion._convert_str_to_tsobject()
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/parsing.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string()
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py in parse(timestr, parserinfo, **kwargs)
>    1373     else:
> -> 1374         return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
>    1375 
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py in parse(self, timestr, default, ignoretz, tzinfos, **kwargs)
>     648         if res is None:
> --> 649             raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
>     650 
>
> ParserError: Unknown string format: 1979-1-1 0
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-89-d112295439b8> in <module>
> ----> 1 dO18Buton.to_netcdf('dO18Buton.nc',
>       2                    engine='netcdf4')
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py in to_netcdf(self, *args, **kwargs)
>    2820             dataset = self.to_dataset()
>    2821 
> -> 2822         return dataset.to_netcdf(*args, **kwargs)
>    2823 
>    2824     def to_dict(self, data: bool = True) -> dict:
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py in to_netcdf(self, path, mode, format, group, engine, encoding,
> ```
>
> unlimited_dims, compute, invalid_netcdf)
> 1898         from ..backends.api import to_netcdf
> 1899
> -> 1900         return to_netcdf(
> 1901             self,
> 1902             path,
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py in to_netcdf(dataset, path_or_file, mode, format, group, engine,
> ```
>
> encoding, unlimited_dims, compute, multifile, invalid_netcdf)
> 1075         # TODO: allow this work (setting up the file for writing array data)
> 1076         # to be parallelized with dask
> -> 1077         dump_to_store(
> 1078             dataset, store, writer, encoding=encoding, unlimited_dims=unlimited_dims
> 1079         )
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py in dump_to_store(dataset, store, writer, encoder, encoding,
> ```
>
> unlimited_dims)
> 1122         variables, attrs = encoder(variables, attrs)
> 1123
> -> 1124     store.store(variables, attrs, check_encoding, writer, unlimited_dims=unlimited_dims)
> 1125
> 1126
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/backends/common.py in store(self, variables, attributes, check_encoding_set, writer,
> ```
>
> unlimited_dims)
> 260             writer = ArrayWriter()
> 261
> --> 262         variables, attributes = self.encode(variables, attributes)
> 263
> 264         self.set_attributes(attributes)
>
> ```
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/backends/common.py in encode(self, variables, attributes)
>     349         # All NetCDF files get CF encoded by default, without this attempting
>     350         # to write times, for example, would fail.
> --> 351         variables, attributes = cf_encoder(variables, attributes)
>     352         variables = {k: self.encode_variable(v) for k, v in variables.items()}
>     353         attributes = {k: self.encode_attribute(v) for k, v in attributes.items()}
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/conventions.py in cf_encoder(variables, attributes)
>     853     _update_bounds_encoding(variables)
>     854 
> --> 855     new_vars = {k: encode_cf_variable(v, name=k) for k, v in variables.items()}
>     856 
>     857     # Remove attrs from bounds variables (issue #2921)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/conventions.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
>     853     _update_bounds_encoding(variables)
>     854 
> --> 855     new_vars = {k: encode_cf_variable(v, name=k) for k, v in variables.items()}
>     856 
>     857     # Remove attrs from bounds variables (issue #2921)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/conventions.py in encode_cf_variable(var, needs_copy, name)
>     267         variables.UnsignedIntegerCoder(),
>     268     ]:
> --> 269         var = coder.encode(var, name=name)
>     270 
>     271     # TODO(shoyer): convert all of these to use coders, too:
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/coding/times.py in encode(self, variable, name)
>     511             variable
>     512         ):
> --> 513             (data, units, calendar) = encode_cf_datetime(
>     514                 data, encoding.pop("units", None), encoding.pop("calendar", None)
>     515             )
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/coding/times.py in encode_cf_datetime(dates, units, calendar)
>     449         units = infer_datetime_units(dates)
>     450     else:
> --> 451         units = _cleanup_netcdf_time_units(units)
>     452 
>     453     if calendar is None:
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/coding/times.py in _cleanup_netcdf_time_units(units)
>     402     delta, ref_date = _unpack_netcdf_time_units(units)
>     403     try:
> --> 404         units = "{} since {}".format(delta, format_timestamp(ref_date))
>     405     except OutOfBoundsDatetime:
>     406         # don't worry about reifying the units if they're out of bounds
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xarray/core/formatting.py in format_timestamp(t)
>     102     # Timestamp is only valid for 1678 to 2262
>     103     try:
> --> 104         datetime_str = str(pd.Timestamp(t))
>     105     except OutOfBoundsDatetime:
>     106         datetime_str = str(t)
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.__new__()
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_to_tsobject()
>
> pandas/_libs/tslibs/conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion._convert_str_to_tsobject()
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp
> ```

How to solve this problem (maybe by using CFTimeIndex)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your `xarray.DataArray` object to a `xarray.Dataset`.

This is very simple:

```py
xarray.Dataset(dO18Buton).to_netcdf('dO18Buton.nc', engine='netcdf4')
```

Comment: I got this error running this command:
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'DataArray`

Comment: When I converted to DataSet object: `dO18Buton.to_dataset().to_netcdf()`. It raise the similar error: alueError: could not convert string to Timestamp